# 2000 Ford Explorer Electrical Problems

Tags: electrical, ford, fuel-system, explorer, pump

Bought an used Ford Explorer a little while back & have since replaced the fuel pump , this will be the fourth time, in a six month period. The battery, the fuel filter, checked all the relays & fuses, replacing the ones that were bad. What causes this? I have found myself in a few different forums that have these same complaints but no answers. Thank you.

Comment: Whats the voltage on the battery with running engine?

Comment: how many amps is the pump pulling? did you check the pump ground wire?

Answer (score 4):

Did you check the user reviews at the source of the fuel pumps. When I replaced mine the two cheapest pumps available had awful reviews. They had a lot of quickly failed comments. Have you inspected the inside of the fuel tank for rust or other contamination? The Explorer has a replaceable pump and a whole assemble available. If you are replacing just the pump and reusing the pick-up and sending unit it is possible that the in tank filter is clogged.